# How to filter JSON document using XQuery?

Tags: json, xpath, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have the following JSON document assigned to a variable as $node:

```
{ "b": "value",
  "c1": 1,
  "c2": 2,
  "d": "",
  "e": ""
}
```

I don't know how to get each single node. I tried as $node//node(). But not getting each single node. I need to query this JSON document to skip the empty nodes & insert into the Marklogic DB, which is mentioned as below:

{ "b": "value",
      "c1": 1,
      "c2": 2
    }

I am new to handle JSON document, kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to help you understand what problem you were probably having iterating over the nodes, you probably had a construct that looked like (in node constructor terms): 
document{object-node{"b":text{"value"}, "c1":number-node{1}, "c2":number-node{2}, ...}}.

So, $node/object-node()/node() addresses the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this matches your needs well, but something like this would work:

```
let $node := xdmp:unquote('
  { "b": "value",
    "c1": 1,
    "c2": 2,
    "d": "",
    "e": ""
  }
')/node()
return xdmp:to-json(map:new((
  for $property in $node/node()
  where string-length(string($property)) > 0
  return
    map:entry(name($property), data($property))
)))
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, this one helps